# Android ClassCast exception with application and context

Tags: android, listview

I am having ClassCast Exception in onitemclick method of a listview. on item click it should goto next activity but on item click app gets force closed and it gives class cast exception at :

**AppData appData =  (AppData) getApplicationContext();**

Here's the code

Usage Activity:

```
 public class UsageActivity extends Activity
        implements OnItemClickListener {

      PackageManager packageManager;
        ListView apkList;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usage);


        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);




        apkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
         apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList, packageManager));

            apkList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }


    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long row) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppData appData =  (AppData) getApplicationContext();
        appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);


        Intent appInfo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApkInfo.class);
        startActivity(appInfo);

}
```

AppData:

```
package com.example.ui_work;


    import android.app.Application;
    import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;

    public class AppData extends Application {

        PackageInfo packageInfo;

        public PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
            return packageInfo;
        }

        public void setPackageInfo(PackageInfo packageInfo) {
            this.packageInfo = packageInfo;
        }

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` returns a `Context` object. It doesn't know about your `AppData` object. Why do you need it to set a `PackageInfo` like that?

Comment: Did you declare your custom `Application` class in the manifest?

Comment: No, i forgot to do that.. its working now..thanx alot